# $x \notin \delta A \implies I_A$ contiuous in $x$

Tags: general-topology

Let $I_A: (X, \mathcal{T}) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the indicatorfunction of $A$. I.e., it takes the value 1 in $A \subseteq X$ and 0 elsewhere. Show that $x \notin \delta A\implies I_A$ is continuous at $x$.

Attempt:

Wlog, $x \notin cl(A)$. Then $I_A(x) = 0$ and we can pick a nbh $V$ of x s.t. $A \cap V$ is empty.

Let $W$ be a neighborhood of 0. It suffices to show that $I_A^{-1}(W)$ is a neighborhood of x. But this is clear, since $V \subseteq I_A^{-1}(W)$.

Indeed, if $v \in V$, then $v \notin A$ and hence $I_A(v) = 0 \in W$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What's $\delta A$?

Comment: The boundary of $A$. I.e. the intersection of the closure of A with the closure of X-A

Comment: It's better to use $\partial A$ for the boundary.

Comment: Then you also need to consider the case when $x$ is an interior point of $A$. The proof will not be very different from the case $x\notin cl(A)$

Comment: That's why I wrote without loss of generality.

Comment: A point must be exactly one of three things: an interior point of $A$, an interior point of $X\setminus A$ which is the same as a point of $X\setminus \overline{A}$, or a point of $\partial A$. In the first two cases $I_A$ is locally constant at $x$.

Comment: As others have indicated, I don't think you can validly say "wlog" here. .. BTW  with $A^c=X\setminus A, $ we always have $X=int(A)\cup int (A^c)\cup \partial A.$  So if $x\in  X\setminus \partial A $ then $I_A$ is constant on an open set $W$ containing $x,$ namely $W= int(A)$ or  $W=int (A^c)$..... The LaTex for  $\partial$ is  \partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider *2 regions*.

Consider first the open region $B=X\backslash(A\cup∂A)$. There you have
$I_A|_B=0$ everywhere. OTOH consider the open region $C=A\backslash∂A$. There you have $I_A|_C=1$ everywhere. That is, in both cases you just have to show that the constant function (with respective value) with an open supporting region will be continuous, which is immediate.

--- rk

Comment: Thanks. But is my proof incorrect? And if so where?

Comment: Your topological view onto continuity looks okay, and inded it is very basic, as I mentioned. You just have to consider both regions, even if both proofs are equivalent. It is not immediate, what you want to address by "wlog". A point does not lay wlog within $B$. But the argument is the same for $C$, and only thence you can say, wlog you choose to consider only $B$ (for that very reason).

Comment: There are two cases to consider: $x \notin clA $ and $x \notin X-cl(A)$. You are saying that I have to adress the second case explicitely? And is the proof of the first case correct then?